# Extending Core Controller isn't Working

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, controllers, extend

I am need of making a change to the Magento function `_checkBaseUrl` found within:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php
```

As best practice I am trying to extend it with my own module so I am not editing the core code and files but it is not working. If I make the change in the core file i get the desired response but when using this it doesn't work. My module is showing up as Enabled in `Configuration > Advanced > Advanced`

Files are as below:

**etc/modules/Me_Coreextend.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Me_Coreextend>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Me_Coreextend>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Me/Coreextend/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Me_Coreextend>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Me_Coreextend>
  </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <core>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                         <Me_Coreextend before="Mage_Core">Me_Coreextend</Me_Coreextend>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </core>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Me/Coreextend/Controller/Varien/Front.php**

I am including only the `_checkBaseUrl` function in this file not the whole contents of `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php` - is this correct? (I have tried to include it all as well but that still doesn't work either)

```
include_once('Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php');
class Me_Coreextend_Controller_Varien_Front extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front
{
    protected function _checkBaseUrl($request)
    {
        // custom changes...
    }
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: That method is used to extend "controllers", you are not dealing with one. My guess would be to get that file in local code pool, but maybe there are better approaches for this.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I was wrongly mistaking the existing `Controller` folder. Copying the one file into my local pool did the trick.

Comment: May be event controller_front_init_routers is worth looking at.

Comment: @odd_duck please add the solution as an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rewrite the class `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front` because it is not initiating by any of Magento factory methods which actually allow us to have rewrite concept.

Front controller is actually initiating in `Mage_Core_Model_App::_initFrontController()` and that method looks like this:

```
protected function _initFrontController()
{
    $this->_frontController = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front();
    Mage::register('controller', $this->_frontController);
    $this->_frontController->init();
    return $this;
}
```

Since it uses regular `$this->_frontController = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front();` class instance intialization, you cannot use any kind of rewrite techniques which is offering by Magento to rewrite this core class.

3 options are there for you :

## 1. Use CodePool Technique

Create new class `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front` in either `local` or `community` codepool and make your changes there.

## 2. Use Events Which Are Triggering In Prior to `_checkBaseUrl()` Function

There are two events happending in prior to invoking `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::_checkBaseUrl()`. They are :

1. `controller_front_init_before`
2. `controller_front_init_routers`

You can use any of these event for your changes if possible.

## 3. Change `Response` Object As Per Your Need

If you check `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::_checkBaseUrl()`, you can see that it validates whether requested uri and base url of Magento instance are same or not. If not, then it will redirect request to the corresponding external url.

So later the case, Magento invokes `response` object to do this redirection. By default, this `response` object is `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http`. So instead of this you can use your own `response` object. All you need to do is specify this in your `index.php` file, while invoking `Mage::run()`.

```
#index.php
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType, array('response' => YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS);
```

Here Magento will use `YOUR_CUSTOM_CLASS` instead of default response object and hence you can do some customization through your custom class.